# How to pass an API key while create a data in post request

Tags: postman

I put this code in my body

```
{
  "contact": {
    "project_id": 1,
    "first_name": "John",
    "address_attributes": {"street1": "12, Street", "city": "Moscow", "country_code": "RU"},
    "tag_list": "vip,cold call" 
  }
}
```

I tried to put an API key in param and header also respectively but every time it gives me  `"403:forbidden" error`
Any help will be grateful.

Comment: What does the api documentation say? an api key would most likely go in the request headers.
More context is needed if you need help.

Comment: If it is coming in as an header, it would most likely be added under the Authorization header usually with the bearer keyword prepended to the api key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to check the API documentation to know how the API keys are to be passed in.

In many cases (not sure if most), this is done by passing it in as an header, usually the Authorization headers.

Most APIs that use this technique require you to add it by adding the header key as Authorization and its value as `'Bearer {API_KEY}'` where {API_KEY} represents the api-key you aim to send.